# Determine loan interest rate from income statements and balance sheets

Tags: loans, financial-statements

I'm trying to determine the loan interest rate from financial statements, e.g https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/VLVLY/balance-sheet?p=VLVLY

Here's what I got

- Interesting expense 1,205,000 = 12.05B
- Current debt 68,878,000 = 68B
- Long term debt 129,586,000 = 129B

Thus Interest rate = `12/(68+129) = 6%`

My questions is

1. Is that the correct way to do it?
2. Since current debt and long term debt has different rates, and the current calculation is an average value. How can I know the individual value?
3. What is the average loan rate an enterprise could get from the bank?

Comment: the first number (interest expense) you moved the decimal point 5 places, the next two you moved it 6 places. You need to check your numbers.

Comment: @mhoran_psprep That's weird, the calculated debt rate became 0.6% which is uncommon.

Comment: Loan rate a business can get depends on the business, the bank, and the current economic conditions. The only answer possible is "shop around and see what's currently available, and keep an eye open for opportunities to refinance at a lower rate should any of those variables change."